# Swagger ui returns error 404 but swagger generates JSON doc

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui

i am clueless. I try to integrate swagger 2.9.2 and swagger ui 2.9.2 in my spring boot app.
I don’t use spring security, i annotated main class with @EnableSwagger2 @EnableWebMvc

I managed to generate JSON documentation under endpoint (http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs) and i managed to access swagger ui under (http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html).

Then i changed literally nothing, refreshed swagger ui page and from then i get error 404 when i try to access swagger UI. I can still access JSON doc.